# Alias method with argument

Tags: ruby

I have a method

```
def press_button(*key_buttons)
  # some interaction to send button 
end
```

and I use this with an argument: `:shift`, `:tab`, `:backspace` etc. I want aliases for this method with a fixed argument so that `press_shift` would stand for `press_button(:shift)`. Is it possible to do this? Or, do I have to wrap this method like:

```
def press_shift
  press_button(:shift)
end
def press_tab
  press_button(:tab)
end
def press_backspace
  press_button(:backspace)
end
```

Comment: Yep, this is the best you can do, I think.

Comment: You are using the term alias wrong.

Comment: What is the point of doing that? If you rename `press_button` to `press`, then you can do `press :shift`. Do you really need to save a single character and do `press_shift`?

Comment: Thanks for fix mistakes, sawa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution for my own question. `method_missing` Ruby hook will help me.

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  if method_name.intern.include?('press')
    argument = /_(\w*)$/.match(method_name.intern)[0]
    press_button(argument.intern)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but I believe this does what you're asking for:

```
[:shift, :tab, :backspace].each do |k|
  define_method("press_#{k}") { press_button(k) }
end
```

Now the methods `press_shift`, `press_tab`, and `press_backspace` are defined.

Comment: My question is: Is there method looks like an `alias_method`, but it must check arguments in `old_name` method?